# Is there a way to make Matlab process output during execution so that the output is available even after user interruption?

Tags: matlab, keyboardinterrupt

Suppose in `func.m` we have

```
function out = func(in)
    for i=1:1000
        out=i;
    end
end
```

and after entering `>> out = func;` in the Matlab cmd, the user interrupts the command execution with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Instead of having `out` equal some integer between 1 and 1000, `out` is not available in the Global Workspace. If `out` had been defined before calling `out = func;`, it would not be updated.

Is there a way to make `out` available in the Global Workspace upon user interruption and during execution of `func` as long as it is defined within `func`?

And if there is a way, will the same method work for cases where a function is interrupted because an error is thrown?

(It may seem trivial if the convenience gained is about a single function. After all, writing to and later reading from harddrive is always an option -- though not an efficient one. Over the years, it's been quite a number of functions where such a functionality would be convenient for me and increase my productivity. So I finally asked.)

Comment: I want to tag something 'interrupt' but the `interrupt` tag has a rather specific meaning. I wonder what other tag happens to be correct.

Comment: I hate to suggest this, but making `out` a global variable would do the trick. This will slow down the function though, and could potentially cause hard to track bugs.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Is there a way to make a function do something before truly stopping after ctrl+c or after a Matlab native error is thrown? I am thinking: make `out` global if that's the case; otherwise, normal. That would circumvent the baggage while achieving the goal.

Comment: No, I don’t think you can do that. You could have your function query a global status (or if a button is pressed in a GUI) every loop iteration to see if it needs to stop. It can then break out of the loop and return normally.

Comment: "where a function is interrupted because an error is thrown" [try/catch](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) can be used in such conditions.

Comment: JFTR: You cannot `catch` a CTRL-C.

Comment: "where a function is interrupted because an error is thrown" Or you can set `dbstop if error`, where the debugger comes up when an error is thrown and you can examine the value of all variables at all levels of the call stack. I don’t think this catches a Ctrl+C though.

Answer (score 1):

So here's a solution that allows to interrupt a loop with a press of a button on a message box.... not ctrl-c, but an alternative way to interrupt a loop:

```
function out=interrupted_loop_example(in) 

f = msgbox('break the loop?') ;

%---------- this is a sample loop:
out=in;
while(~breakloop(f))   
       out=out+1;
end
%--------------------------------

% clean up:
if ishandle(f) ;  delete(f) ;  end %  to kill the msgbox

% helper function
function x = breakloop(f)
    drawnow ;          % allowing matlab to detect a button was pressed
    x = ~ishandle(f) ;
```

copy the function, run it, e.g. `interrupted_loop_example(100)` , and see the ans when you press the button, basically deciding when to break the loop. naturally there will be a toll on performance this way, but you didn't mention anything about performance in your question.